# Get date months with iteration over Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem case to iterate for last 36 months based on an input date. Currently using Scala, through a `DataFrame` I am getting the max value of a timestamp field. For example:

```
val vGetDate = hc.read.format("filodb.spark").option("database","YYYYY").option("dataset","XXX").load().agg(max("inv_date").alias("max_date"))
```

For example date comes as `2017-12-01 00:00:00`.

Now I need to iterate to get the dates for last 36 months.

Note, I am using Spark 1.4 over Cassandra with FiloDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had access to Spark 1.5+ you could do that easily with the [`year`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@year(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [`month`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@month(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) functions, but since you only have access to Spark 1.4 you'll have to replicate their functionality in UDFs, as follows:

```
val year = udf {
  (s: String) =>
    java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(s).getYear
}

val month = udf {
  (s: String) =>
    java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(s).getMonth
}

def monthDiff(a: Column, b: Column): Column =
  (year(a) - year(b)) * 12 + (month(a) - month(b))
```

Then you can use this UDF with a `where` clause to filter your `DataFrame` as I should in this example:

```
final case class Data(date: String)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(Data("2017-04-01 00:00:00")))

val since = lit("2018-01-01 00:00:00")

assert(df.where(monthDiff(since, $"date") < 36).count == 1)

assert(df.where(monthDiff(since, $"date") < 4).count == 0)
```

Regarding your need to *iterate*, what you usually want to take when using the Spark DataFrame API is a *declarative* approach, using `groupBy` statements to aggregate by your key. For example, your original query can be expressed as follows ():

```
val vGetDate = 
  hc.read.format("filodb.spark").option("database","YYYYY").option("dataset","XXX").load().
  where(monthDiff(lit(startDate), "inv_date")).
  groupBy(concat(year("inv_date"), lit("-"), lpad(month("inv_date"), 2, "0"))).
  agg(max("inv_date").alias("max_date"))
```

Here, you produce the latest date for all groups (defined by the grouping key as the year and month with the format `yyyy-MM` whose `"inv_date"` is no more than 36 months apart from some `startDate`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. However, I have few confusion as I am new to scala and spark.

Comment: @Rajdip Sure, feel free to ask, I'll gladly improve my answer to match your needs. :)

Comment: I don't know the end date. SO I need to find all the year months of last 36 months starting from a date

Comment: I edited the answer to better reflect your question, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Rajdip If you found the post useful, could you upvote it? Thanks.